# how to put a vertical dotted bar in a layout

Tags: android

I'm designing a layout for some listview items and I would like to draw a vertical dotted line to separate the content from some button on the right of the row, like in the example I attached. What is the best way to do it? And moreover: is there a way to obtain it by setting up some widget's property (something like setting up a css property for a border)?

Thanks

[image: example of what I wanna get]

Comment: Make the graphic with dots and put it in as a simple ImageView between the phone button and the list content area... Pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the best way to do it?

Put the widgets, including a new `View` for your divider, into a horizontal `LinearLayout`. Use a `ShapeDrawable` as the background for the `View`, where the `ShapeDrawable` defines your desired dash pattern.

Note that most UIs that have this sort of divider use a solid line.

> is there a way to obtain it by setting up some widget's property

You can try to [use `android:drawableLeft` and similar propertie](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3adrawableLeft)s instead of the `LinearLayout`, if one of the widgets in this row is a `TextView` or inherits from it.